# if called window is already running then close it and run newly called window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my app in several time i have to call a window(class). the work of this window is to show the meaning of a word.when i again call that window a new window shows but the previous one  also shows.
I have two form named `form1`,`form2`.

Form1 is like that:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
         string a = textBox1.Text;
         Form2 s = new Form2(a);// it will be called as many time as i click
         s.Show();
    }
}
```

Form2 is like that:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(string s)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = s;
    }
}
```

what i want is that inside form1 if i call form2 it shows but if i call form2 again the previous form2 window will be closed automatically and new form2 window will be shown instead of previous one.
How can i do that????

Comment: Don't create a new window (`new show_meaning(x)`) each time, and show the the same form instance.

Comment: +1 @l4v.  Store the reference to the word meaning form as a class-level variable and refer to it each time you need it.

Comment: And use the FormClosed event to know that the window was closed by the user, set the reference back to null.

Comment: How can i store the reference as class-level variable???@Adrian

Comment: I have to pass a word into the show_meaning class every-time .@I4V

Comment: I couldn't understand how to use that.@HansPassant

Comment: @DarkenShooter `form.FormClosed += (s,e)=> form = null;`  That's all it takes.

Comment: You said: "the previous form2 window will be closed automatically and new form2 window will be shown"  The singleton pattern you've accepted keeps multiple forms from showing, but it does not close the previous one and open a new one.  It keeps the **same** instance alive and shows it over and over...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of storing the Form2 reference at class level, as mentioned by the others already:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Form2 f2 = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f2 != null && !f2.IsDisposed)
        {
            f2.Dispose();    
        }

        string a = textBox1.Text;
        f2 = new Form2(a);
        f2.Show();
    }

}
```

Comment: what i want is that inside form1 if i call form2 it shows but if i call form2 again the previous form2 window will be closed automatically and new form2 window will be shown instead of previous one

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using singleton pattern.

You can implement it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
         string a = textBox1.Text;
         Form2.ShowMeaning(a);// it will be called as many time as you click
    }
}
```

and Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private static readonly Form2 _formInstance = new Form2();

    private Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LoadMeaning(string s)
    {
        label1.Text = s;
    }

    //Override method to prevent disposing the form when closing.
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }

    public static void ShowMeaning(string s)
    {
        _formInstance.LoadMeaning(s);
        _formInstance.Show();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: look i have 2 form named form1,form2. inside form1 "show_meaning s = new show_meaning(x);s.Show();" is called as many times as i want.but the show_meaning(x) is insid form2.can you give any easy way of that??? @VahidND

Comment: Your definition of show_meaning() does not define a return value so I considered it as a constructor. I rename methods to match your naming for better understanding, but I may help you further if you provide your complete code for form2.

Comment: It seems you've got your answer but I updated my answer for completeness.